# High chart width issue

Tags: highcharts

```
{
   colors: ['red','#009966'],
   chart: {
          height: 150,
          width: 350,
          type: 'bar',
          backgroundColor: '#efefef',
          marginLeft:150
         },
   title: {
          text: 'Workgroup Ticket in SLA',
          style: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '16px'
          }
    },
    xAxis: {
           x:-15,
           y:2,
           lineColor: '#82CAFF',
           lineWidth: 1,
           categories: ['AS Front End Eng.', 'AS FFE Support', 'AS UI Transaction','AS UI Merchandizing','AS UI Infrastructure','AS Website Festures'],
           labels: {
           style: {
                   color: 'black',
                   fontSize: '8px',
                   fontWeight: 'bold',
                   fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                  }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                lineColor: '#82CAFF',
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineDashStyle: 'dot',
                tickPositions: [0,20,40,60,80,100],
                width:160,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: '9px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false,
                backgroundColor: '',
                reversed: true
            },
            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',                      
                }
            },
                series: [ {
                name: '',
                data: [0, 5, 62, 50, 22,22]
            },
                         {
                name: '',
                data: [100,95,38,50,78,78]
           }
     ]
 }
```

This is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/SMrKu/

I want to remove the extra space created in boxh left and right hand side of the high chart.

But on reducing the width it is showing error in high chart.

Comment: marginLeft:110,marginRight:30 


in this way I have reduced the extra space. Anyway rightside space is something that the API needs to display its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than reducing the width, reduce the margin-Left

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

EDIT: You can reduce spacingLeft and spacingRight http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingLeft

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SMrKu/1/ with marginLeft=120.But i want to remove the right side extra space.

Comment: issue was with width given in Y axis

I have removed width height for the chart and width for y axis as well. All margin widths have been removed as well.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have removed all width .but now the graph is very large.I want a small graph

Comment: simple ..just add width and height chart properties to highcharts main container..
check JSfiddle 



http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

Comment: Yes that was done.Is there any api in high chart is there for viewbox.Because in svg view box is there.So any similar api is there for viewbox in high chart.

Comment: please check the highcharts api for this. i the meantime, if your original question has been answered, pls consider, accepting the answer

Answer (score 2):

you can set spacingLeft and spacingRight property.

```
chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        spacingLeft:0,
        spacingRight:0,
    },
```

you can check the example on below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/vpL0j2av/1/